# Can an eigenvector correspond to more than one eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can an eigenvector correspond to more than one eigenvalue, assuming the eigenvalues are different?

Answer (score 4):

No; if $v$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $A$ for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then
$$\lambda v=Av=\mu v,$$
and hence $(\lambda-\mu)v=0$, which implies that $v=0$, contradicting the fact that $v$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. This gives us $Tv=\lambda_1v$, $Tv=\lambda_2 v\implies \lambda_1v=\lambda_2v$, contrary to $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$ (because $v$ is nonzero).